# Greater than operator not working in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, operator-keyword

Could anyone suggest why the greater than operator is being ignored in this MySQL query?

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM `items`
WHERE `short_description` LIKE '%".$term."%'
    OR `description` LIKE '%".$term."%'
    AND `quantity` > 0
ORDER BY year DESC, denomination ASC, description ASC $max";
```

I have a similar query on the same site that works

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM `items`
WHERE `category` = '".$cat_id."'
    AND `quantity` > 0
ORDER BY year DESC, denomination ASC, description ASC;";
```

Everything works well, except the quantity comparison on the first query, Its has got me stumped.

Comment: What does your `description ASC $max";` mean?

Comment: relates to turning the results in to pages using the statement $max = LIMIT 5 created in an option earlier in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM `items`
WHERE (`short_description` LIKE '%".$term."%'
    OR `description` LIKE '%".$term."%')
    AND `quantity` > 0
ORDER BY year DESC, denomination ASC, description ASC $max";
```

I am thinking that your `OR` statement is the problem.

Comment: Yes, great, thanks to all, I learn every day. I really do appreciate the prompt responses for a non-professional like me!

Answer (score 0):

you should group your `OR` and `AND` conditions by enclosing them in a parenthesis,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `items` 
         WHERE  (`short_description` LIKE '%".$term."%' OR 
                 `description` LIKE '%".$term."%')  AND 
                  `quantity` > 0 
          ORDER BY year DESC, denomination ASC, description ASC $max";
```

*followup question: is `$max` a variable which contains `LIMIT` clause?*

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Ok, have heard of that, do you know of a good reference where i can learn more about this type of hack? Thanks

Comment: Would using mysql_real_escape_string to convert the user input be enough?

Comment: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/5741264#5741264)

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE (short_description LIKE '%".$term."%' OR description LIKE 
'%".$term."%') 
AND quantity > 0 
ORDER BY year DESC, denomination ASC, description ASC $max";
```

Try that... You have an Or condition, and an and.

Comment: Yes, great, thanks to all, I learn every day. I really do appreciate the prompt responses for a non-professional like me!

Answer (score 0):

It's not being ignored, it's just that you misunderstand how it's being applied. The expression:

```
WHERE `short_description` LIKE '%".$term."%' (call this XX,)
OR `description` LIKE '%".$term."%'          (          YY,)
AND `quantity` > 0                           (      and ZZ.)
```

is interpreted as:

```
where XX or (YY and ZZ)
```

whereas what you probably want is:

```
where (XX or YY) and ZZ
```

Hence you have to override the default interpretation as follows:

```
WHERE (`short_description` LIKE '%".$term."%' OR
       `description` LIKE '%".$term."%')
  AND `quantity` > 0
```

The reason your second query doesn't have this problem is because you're not mixing `AND` and `OR`.

---

In addition, though unrelated to your *specific* question), you should be *very* wary of double-ended `like` clauses such as `like '%something%'`. They're real performance killers for decent sized tables and there are ways to improve the performance considerably.

It may not matter in this case if your tables are small but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Yes, great, thanks to all, I learn every day. I really do appreciate the prompt responses for a non-professional like me!